# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'

Tags: tensorflow-model-analysis

I'm trying to eval my model trained with tensorflow object detection api.

Run:

`python eval.py --logtostderr --pipeline_config_path=ssd_inception_v2_coco.config --checkpoint_dir=models/train/ --evad_dir=eval`

And have:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/eval.py", line 50, in <module>
    from object_detection import evaluator
  File "/jet/prs/models/research/object_detection/evaluator.py", line 24, in <module>
    from object_detection import eval_util
  File "/jet/prs/models/research/object_detection/eval_util.py", line 28, in <module>
    from object_detection.metrics import coco_evaluation
  File "/jet/prs/models/research/object_detection/metrics/coco_evaluation.py", line 20, in <module>
    from object_detection.metrics import coco_tools
  File "/jet/prs/models/research/object_detection/metrics/coco_tools.py", line 47, in <module>
    from pycocotools import coco
  File "/jet/prs/models/research/pycocotools/coco.py", line 49, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/jet/var/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/jet/var/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 62, in pylab_setup
    [backend_name], 0)
  File "/jet/var/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import tkagg  # Paint image to Tk photo blitter extension.
  File "/jet/var/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py", line 5, in <module>
    from six.moves import tkinter as Tk
  File "/jet/var/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 92, in __get__
    result = self._resolve()
  File "/jet/var/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/jet/var/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/jet/var/python/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

Thought that I didn't properly install all dependencies, but `Testing the Installation` from that [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md) says that it's ok.

Comment: This usually occurs because of Python not installed properly. Try this command to install pyhton-tk using `sudo apt-get install python-tk`. Once installed check if you could import tkinter `import tkinter `

Comment: Or repairing python using the installer (what I had to do because `tkinter` was being annoying and buggy)